# How to delete the row from mysql table in this PHP code?

Tags: php

The code below is meant to delete the record who's id is the one rendered on the page from the query select. I am having problems how to delete that row . So instead of id = '233'" get the table id and delete. Can you kindly look in this code, and suggest a solution?Thanks

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">

<?php


/* New Code */
//if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
if (isset($_POST['formSubmit']))

{
$courseid=$_POST['rowid'];
$db8=& JFactory::getDBO();
$db8->setQuery("DELETE FROM jos_jquarks_persontraining WHERE
  id = '233'");
 $db8->query();
echo $courseid;

}

$database =& JFactory::getDBO();
// Display enrollments
echo "<h1>";
echo "<span style='text-decoration: underline;'>";
echo "Courses : " ;
echo "</h1>";
echo "</b>";

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

$database->setQuery("SELECT jos_jquarks_persontraining.id as trainingid,training.training, 
DATE_FORMAT(training.trainingDate, '%W, %M %e, %Y'),
training.trainingHour, training.course_location,
date_format(jos_jquarks_persontraining.timeStamp,'%m/%d/%Y')  
FROM jos_jquarks_persontraining 
INNER JOIN training ON  jos_jquarks_persontraining.training_id = training.training_id
WHERE
  jos_jquarks_persontraining.user_id =  " .$id  ) ;

if (!$database->query()) 
{ 
    echo "<script> alert('".$database->getErrorMsg()."'); </script>";
}

$tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px solid black"; 
$tdStyle = "padding:5px"; 
$thStyle = "padding:7px";

$row = $database->loadRowList();
if ( 0<count($row)) {
    echo '<table style="', $tableStyle, '" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">';  
    echo '<tr><th style="', $thStyle, '" align=center>Id</th><th style="', $thStyle, '" align=center>Course</th><th style="', $thStyle, '" align=center>Date</th>
    <th style="', $thStyle, '" align=center>Time</th>
<th style="', $thStyle, '" align=center>Location</th>

<th style="', $thStyle, '" align=center>Enrollment Date</th>
<th style="', $thStyle, '" align=center>Action</th>'; 


    $row = $database->loadRowList();
    foreach($row as $valuearray) {
        echo '<tr align="center">';

        foreach($valuearray as $field){
            echo '<td style="', $tdStyle, '" align=center>', $field, '</td>'; 

        } // field
        echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr align="center">';
echo'<td>';
//echo '<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Unenroll" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="'.$row['ID'].'" ]" />';
echo '<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Unenroll" />';

echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';


    } // $valuearray
    echo '</table>'; 
}
 // if count
?>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to delete a table or a row?  What's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: Is a row sorry. I have table like : id, employeeid, name, etc,

Comment: Then delete the row that you want to delete.  Again, what's stopping you?

Comment: This is  the primary key to which I am selecting and need to delete->>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $database->setQuery("SELECT jos_jquarks_persontraining.id as trainingid  But my code is not deleting nothing

Comment: 0_o That's the beginning of a `select` statement, not a `delete` statement.  Hence, no, it wouldn't delete anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
$db8->setQuery("DELETE FROM jos_jquarks_persontraining WHERE
  id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."'");
```

Comment: can this be database->setquery instead ?

Comment: Will that get the mysql id in each row for deleting that row?